# Skipping over .asm code in Xcode4 debugger

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I'm using Xcode4 and the debugger keeps jumping into .asm code when I select jump over.  I don't know .asm and just want the next line of ObjC code.  Is there some setting to have it not show the .asm code?
Thanks!

Comment: You're definitely not supposed to ask two questions at a time. Please edit your post down to one question, and make another post for the second.

Answer (score 1):

Which debugger you are using? LLVM or GDB. (You can find out at the menu product->edit scheme  as shown figure below).

[image]

If the debugger is LLDB, try to switch it back to GDB and see that fix your problem.